# datetime.now() not accurate

Tags: django, datetime, digital-ocean

I have a Django application which automatically takes in a timezone.now()  value as a field in a model. When I run this on localhost, it works as expected. However, when I deployed it onto Digital Ocean, timezone.now()  takes the value of the time when I started running the server. Why does this happen and how can I work around this?

Correction: django's timezone.now()

Answer (score 5):

Code would have been helpful.

Presumably you are using this as the `default` argument to a field. The problem is that you have done this:

```
my_field = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

which, due to the way Python works, is evaluated when the class is *defined* - ie when the process starts. Instead, you should pass the *callable*:

```
my_field = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

that is, without the calling parentheses, and Django will know to call it on instantiation.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, but why does running the server on my local machine not create an issue, but a remote server does?

Comment: Well it does, but on your local machine you're restarting the dev server all the time - it restarts itself whenever your code changes. If you'd left your dev server running for more than a day, with no code changes, you'd see the same thing.

Comment: Good answer. That's why I prefer to use auto_now_add parameter: created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: I'm not making any changes to the code on my local machine, I'm simply adding an entry into the database, so I'm not understanding why that issue is happening.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you saying you've left the dev server running on your local machine over multiple days, with no restarts or code changes, and then when you add an item in the admin it uses the current date?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because it's caching the result of running that method, instead of running it again each time it's called, as I've run into this in Ruby on Rails. In your local environment, caching is probably not turned on since that would be annoying for development. In Ruby you can just wrap the method call in a lambda, which I assume would also work in Python, but I haven't tried.